# smart light wire "interceptor"

Tags: lighting, home-automation

I went to showroom recently and they showed me a product (which I've now forgotten the name of) which is basically a box that behind the wall or in the ceiling - it connects to wifi and is essentially a hidden switch. You can then connect via an app and switch lights on and off etc.

I like this idea because I can use my own choice of light switch and there's no restriction on the type/model of LED light that I install.

What is the class of these devices called? And who is doing them? All my internet searches keep coming to the regular wall-switch ones like lightwaverf.

Answer (score 2):

Argh, typical right after I post a question I find the answer myself.

They're called "in-line modules" or "in-line switches". And there's plenty of companies that do it.